# Send two topics in push notification using FCM

Tags: laravel

'token' => "/topics/$user_country || /topics/$userType",

How to send two topics in that code i want to choose scpecific country and specific usertype and pass to that two topics. for example I selected a specific country example is US and then I selected Free Users in usertype .. so that two topics the country selected and the usertype will be pass to the 'token' and it will it will notify only to the Users in US which are Free Users but when I add the two topics I get 500 internal server error.